# INT_32_BE in PBKDF2

Tags: pbkdf-2, salt, pseudo-random-function

Trying to understand [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) in detail. It is clear that the password and the salt is given to the PRF (which is HMAC-SHA-1 in [the specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt)). But what is the role of the INT_32_BE(i)? What does it call?  Is it ORed (`||`) with the salt?  And what is the value of INT_32_BE(i) any way? Is it 1? Can anyone clear this out?

```
U1 = PRF(Password, Salt || INT_32_BE(i))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you linked to explains everyting

> Salt concatenated with i encoded as a big-endian 32-bit integer

So, || is concatenation, INT_32_BE is a function that encodes the 32 bit integer i as big endian. On a big endian system, INT_32_BE would do nothing. On a little endian architecture, it would do the encoding.

i goes from 1 to dklen/hlen. dklen/hlen is the number of hash function outputs needed to construct a key of the right length.

Comment: huh??? ... say what..?

Comment: @Giliweed, what is not clear? [Endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?

Comment: I'm not clear about what is "big endian"

Comment: I suppose it bears mentioning that the purpose is to make each block of the output different.